# Bouncy Castle not working on linux machine

Tags: java, linux, windows, bouncycastle, fips

I implemented boucnyCastle for fips complaint signature generation and verification, this worked fine on a windows environment but on a linux environment the code is stuck on keypair generation. Following is the code that i have written:

```
public static KeyPair generateKeyPair() throws GeneralSecurityException
{
    KeyPairGenerator keyPair = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BCFIPS");
    keyPair.initialize(new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(3072, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F4));
    return keyPair.generateKeyPair();
}
```

[Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/fips_faq.html)

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work" and "is stuck"? What happens? Do you get an error message?

Comment: it gives no error  and neither moves to the next line of the code, to be specific it is stuck on this "return keyPair.generateKeyPair();"

Comment: Does your Linux system have enough entropy? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#Not_enough_random_bytes_available

Comment: @DragonAssassin i increased my entropy limit to 4000 but still same problem prebiously it was some where around 200.

Comment: @AbdulAhad It appears that Bouncy Castle uses alot of entropy.To get enough I had to install Haveged to generate artificial entropy. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Haveged

Comment: @DragonAssassin thank you, following your suggestion we fixed our problem using answer mentioned below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First Check if rngd.service (Hardware RNG Entropy Gatherer Daemon) is running on your system. If you are using Virtual Machine then it will not be running and to fix it use the following link:

http://wiki.networksecuritytoolkit.org/index.php/HowTo_Fix_The_rngd.service

Second check if your system has enough entropy using command:

> cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail

if Entropy of your system has not enough Entropy then increase it. you can use the following link:

https://redhatlinux.guru/index.php/2016/04/03/increase-system-entropy-on-rhel-centos-6-and-7/

Also Install Haveged on your system to generate artificial entropy. To install Haveged you can use the 
following link:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-additional-entropy-for-cloud-servers-using-haveged