# Bouncy Castle for fips is not working on linux virtual machine

Tags: java, linux, windows, bouncycastle, fips

I implemented Bouncy Castle for fips certificate generation, this worked fine on physical   linux environment  but  on linux virtual machine the code is stuck on keypair generation. Following is the code that i have written:

```
public static KeyPair generateKeyPair() throws GeneralSecurityException
{
    KeyPairGenerator keyPair = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", 
      "BCFIPS");
    keyPair.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());
    return keyPair.generateKeyPair();
}
```

I found a similar post but its not working for me.  [Bouncy Castle not working on linux machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47795876/bouncy-castle-not-working-on-linux-machine)

Initially current entropy value is 1700 (as per the steps given it should be 3000-4000). I tried the steps given and entropy value is increased to 2600 (as per the steps given it should be above 4000).

Post that i tried generating certificate and issue was still there.

I tried increasing threshold value by "kernel.random.read_wakeup_threshold = 4096" "kernel.random.write_wakeup_threshold = 6144"

When i execute "sysctl -p" , it throws error..

" sysctl: setting key "kernel.random.read_wakeup_threshold": Invalid argument kernel.random.read_wakeup_threshold = 4096 sysctl: setting key "kernel.random.write_wakeup_threshold": Invalid argument kernel.random.write_wakeup_threshold = 6144 "

I run "yum install haveged" command, And it says package haveged is already installed.

haveged configuration looks fine..

```
rngtest: starting FIPS tests...
rngtest: bits received from input: 20000032
rngtest: FIPS 140-2 successes: 1000
rngtest: FIPS 140-2 failures: 0
rngtest: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Monobit: 0
rngtest: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Poker: 0
rngtest: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Runs: 0
rngtest: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Long run: 0
rngtest: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Continuous run: 0
rngtest: input channel speed: (min=1.977; avg=13.431; max=23.782)Mibits/s
rngtest: FIPS tests speed: (min=116.302; avg=143.533; max=147.856)Mibits/s
rngtest: Program run time: 1561023 microseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find the approach detailed in the second half of the BCFIPS user guide will work for you. Using the HYBRID configuration enables an entropy pool in the BouncyCastleFipsProvider which will help stretch out the available entropy in a compliant fashion.